# Problem enabling the user to edit Markdown and displaying the HTML output (WMD Editor plugin for Wordpress)

Tags: plugins, visual-editor

Here is the [WMD Editor implementation for Wordpress](http://c.hadcoleman.com/wordpress-plugins/wmd-editor-wordpress-plugin/).

**When the users writes a post everything is displayed OK:**

[image]

[image]

**The problem is when the user clicks EDIT:**

[image]

The HTML version is the one displayed (I think it is a normal behaviour since WMD Editor turned the Markdown version of the post into HTML).
What are the steps to fix this? or IS there a new version which solves this?
(I checked other questions but no one gives a concrete solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the normal way for it to work, when you save it turns the markdown text to html, so when you edit you need to reverse the html back to markdown text.

there is an outdated plugin that has most of the functions you need it http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress/
that would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks man, I will check it out. (By the way, are you playing with bbPress too?).

Comment: Nope, i use simplepress